# GO Looping Data from struct and converting it to an array of strings to make a CSV

Tags: arrays, csv, go, struct

I am trying to get my data into a CSV. I am very close. The problem I have now is that the CSV Writer expects a []string. But I cannot figure out how to get my data from the struct into one []string. I am looping though my json data and appending it to create a new model. How do I get my model to be accepted?

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "bitbucket.org/exzeo-usa/devops-aws-report/models"
)


func CreateCSV(incidents models.IncidentModel) {

    fmt.Println("Creating CSV...")

    m := []models.EndModel{}

    for i := range incidents.Incidents {

        m = append(m, models.EndModel{
            IncidentNumber: strconv.Itoa(incidents.Incidents[i].IncidentNumber),
            Title:          incidents.Incidents[i].Title,
            CreatedAt:      incidents.Incidents[i].CreatedAt,
            Notes:          GetNotes(incidents.Incidents[i].IncidentNumber),
        })
    }
    fmt.Print(m)
    writeCSV(m)
    return
}

//writeCSV is a function create a .csv file
func writeCSV(allData []models.EndModel) {

    today := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02")
    fileString := fmt.Sprintf("result-%v.csv", today)

    //Create File
    file, err := os.Create(fileString)
    checkError("Cannot create file", err)
    defer file.Close()

    //Create the writer with the file
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    //Create and Write to the CSV
    err = writer.Write(allData)
    checkError("Cannot write to file...", err)

}

func checkError(message string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(message, err)
    }
}
```

Comment: And why not `func writeCSV(allData [][]string)`?

Comment: Because my struct isn't a [][]string, the function with reject the argument. Is there a way to make the struct a [][]string ?

Comment: You cannot. You must create a []string and populate it from your struct, there is no magic for this step in Go.

Comment: How would I get my appended data into a []struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you cannot simply map from one type to another and have the compiler figure out how to convert your data. Other languages may provide some syntactic sugar or have some precedent for inferring a sensible default, but Go deliberately does not offer such magic.

You will need to be explicit in indicating how to convert each instance of your `models.EndModel` data structure into a slice of `[]string` to be written out as a CSV row.

Something like the following:

```golang
// writeCSV is a function create a .csv file
func writeCSV(allData []models.EndModel) {

    today := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02")
    fileString := fmt.Sprintf("result-%v.csv", today)

    //Create File
    file, err := os.Create(fileString)
    checkError("Cannot create file", err)
    defer file.Close()

    // Create the writer with the file
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    // Create and Write to the CSV
    csvRows := make([][]string, len(allData))
    for i, model := range allData {
        csvRows[i] = []string{
            // Choose the ordering you wish in your output CSV
            model.IncidentNumber,
            model.Title,
            model.CreatedAt,
            model.Notes,
        }
    }

    // Note that you need to call WriteAll to pass multiple rows
    err = writer.WriteAll(csvRows)
    checkError("Cannot write to file...", err)

}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you!  I finally have a CSV. Thank you Cosmic!